# Why does Iterator remove an extra item

Tags: java, iterator

I used an iterator and a while loop to print out all the entries of an `ArrayList`.

I also used a `for` loop to print out all the entries of the same `ArrayList`.

I tried to remove an item with the iterator. It seems that it has been removed properly from the `ArrayList`, but the While loop also removed one more item "Mary".

This is the resource code.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("John");
    names.add("Mary");
    names.add("George");
    names.add("Nick");

    Iterator<String> iterator = names.iterator();

    System.out.println("Iterator method: ");
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
        if (iterator.next().equals("Nick")){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nFOR loop method: ");
    for (int i=0; i < names.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
}
```

Why has "Mary" has been removed?

```
Iterator method: 
John
George

FOR loop method: 
John
Mary
George

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You call `iterator.next()` twice, so of course it increments twice (and skip `Mary`). It's doing what you're telling it to do, so what don't you understand?

Comment: Whenever you all iterator.next you change the position. That's why you need to call one time inside the loop inside a variable.

Comment: SO is not a great tutorial site. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) so iterator makes two steps. If you want to perform more actions on the [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) returned by [`iterator.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) you need to store this value in a variable and do these operations with the use of this variable.

Change these lines:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next()); // first valie returned by iterator
    if (iterator.next().equals("Nick") { // second value returned by the iterator
        iterator.remove(); // second value returned by the iterator removed 
    }
}
```

to:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator.next(); // here you store value returned by the iterator to make proper checks further
    System.out.println(s); // here you use created variable instead of calling next()
    if (s.equals("Nick") {, // again, created variable instead of next()
        iterator.remove(); // here you remove last value returned by the iterator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `next()` eats an entry from the Iterator.  You compare Mary and Nick to Nick, and print out John and George.

Only invoke `next()` once in the loop, and save it in a variable which you then use for printing and comparing.

Answer (score 0):

the next() method is called twice

- once inside the System.out.println()
- once inside the if()